# In bash script, what is difference between > and >| redirections?

Tags: linux, bash, mac-osx, unix, sh

What is the difference between the following two redirection commands?

```
ls > out
ls >| out
```

They both seem to produce the same output.

Answer (score 3):

According to [1] the difference is that `>|` redirects the output to a file even if noclobber option is set.

noclobber option is set by bash's command line option `-C` and prevents overwriting of files by redirection [2]. When the noclobber option is set, then `ls >| out` overwrittes the file `out`, while `ls > out` does not.

[1] http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html
[2] http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html#NOCLOBBERREF